# How do I access SQLite database instance on iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite

I'm developing an iPhone app that uses the built-in SQLite database. I'm trying to view and open the database via the `sqlite3` command line tool so I can execute arbitrary SQL against it.

When I run my app in the simulator, the `.sqlite` file it creates is located at `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/`.

How can I see that file on the physical iPhone?

Comment: Note the simulator location is now ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/<version of iOS>/Applications (just for anybody finding this via google)

Comment: The simulator directory has been moved with Xcode 6 to: ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator. To find the unique path add the following statement to the AppDelegate.m file, applicationDocumentsDirectory method:  NSLog(@"%@",[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]);

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In Xcode select window->organizer and expand the node next to your application in the applications section on your phone.  Select the black downward pointing arrow next to application data and save the file anywhere on your desktop.  Your sqlite database should be in there somewhere.

As for how to go about getting it back on the phone once your done i have no clue.

Comment: What if i have downloaded my app from the app store?As it won't list down in the applications???Please help me out to find the possible way so that i can validate the things. correct me if i am wrong :)thanks in adv...

Comment: @ravoorinandan in the Organizer click the "Applications" under the device your testing on.  Your applications on that device will appear in the right pane.  Select your desired app, then click "Download" button at the bottom of the Organizer window.  Save this to your desktop.  Just right click the downloaded .xcappdata and select "Show Package Contents."  Finder will open, follow AppData > Documents > the database file will be in there.  You may need a viewer like SQLite DBB to see the data in a conventional manner.

Comment: The answer below this one applies to newer versions of XCode and worked for me for those of you who have made changes to your dev environment since 2008...

Answer (score 84):

Instructions for Xcode 6.0.1

1. Xcode > Open > YourProject
2. Xcode > Product > Run
3. Xcode > Window > Devices
4. (Column 1 - select) Devices > YourDeviceName
5. (Column 2 - select) Installed Apps > YourAppName
6. (Column 2 - select) Cog under 'Installed Apps' list
7. (Pop-Up - select) Download Container...
8. Save to location
9. Right click on 'YourAppName.xcappdata'
10. Select 'Show Package Contents'
11. AppData > Documents > YourDatabase.sqlite

[image]

Comment: Stack overflow suggests not saying 'thanks' in a comment but I can't help myself.  This information was extremely useful.  That's great that there's a way to get the sqlite DB off the phone for checking.  thank you!

Comment: I have added a screenshot for clarification

Comment: As long as the app is installed you can skip the first 2 steps and just go to window > devices once xcode is opened. (This is useful as I'm deploying a cordova app and do not deploy from xcode)

Answer (score 2):

In XCode 4, you do the same as Lounges suggested, which will save the whole file structure for your app to your destination of choice. Rename the .xcappdata file which is saved to .sqlite so you can open it by double clicking, then you can find the file from the device.

Comment: This works great, although it doesn't matter what you change the file extension to. For example, I just renamed the .xcappdata file to "files" and the Finder recognizes it as a folder.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly in the same way you do on the simulator. There are very few (important) differences between the device and simulator, and file access and library loading are for the most part not part of them.

Comment: thanks millenomi ... i updated my question to better express my problem. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your question remains a little vague. "See" in what sense? Do you create the SQLite database? How? Have you placed it manually in the Simulator's filesystem area? Are you perhaps asking how to do that on the iPhone?

The easiest way is to precreate an empty database with the sqlite3 command-line tool, have it as a resource in your application, then copy it in your application sandbox's documents folder. You can get the path to your resources folder via NSBundle's pathForResource:ofType: method, then grab the path to your Documents folder via NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains() for the NSDocumentsDirectory folder in the NSUserDomainMask, then copy the file via NSFileManager's methods.

Otherwise, you can use SQLite's functions to create a new database from scratch by supplying appropriate SQL commands to define its schema.

Answer (score 1):

This one works if you jailbreak your iPhone.. I don't know why anyone would have any issues with jailbreaking their phone as I've been using it for development for quite some time and found no problems, also it is not uncommon for sqlite to [perform differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462951/ios-sqlite3-memory-management-behaving-differently-between-device-and-simulator) on the device vs simulator:

1. Jail break your phone (there tutorials all over the web)
2. Set your cydia user level to [developer](http://www.jailbreakqa.com/questions/135484/why-cant-i-find-sqlite3-in-cydiatelesphoreo)
3. Install sqlite3 into your phone:  go to cydia > manage > sources > cydia/telesphoreo > sqlite3
4. ssh into your phone using [iphone tunnel](http://code.google.com/p/iphonetunnel-mac/) root ssh password: "alpine"
5. Type `which sqlite3` to ensure you have it installed
6. browse to the location of your db.. a breakpoint in your code should tell you where it is located.. in my code it looks something like this

   ```
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
   NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex: 0]; 
   NSString *pathName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
   return pathName;
   ```

   Notice that if you run this on the simulator.. you'll get a location like the following:
   `/Users/admin/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/42302574-7722-48C1-BE00-91800443DA7C/Documents/email-524200.edb`

On the device it will look like this:
`/var/mobile/Applications/FB73857F-A822-497D-A4B8-FBFB269A8699/Documents/email-523600.edb`

Then just type `sqlite3 %dbname%` and you can execute sql statements right on your phone.. without copying it over or whatever.

Comment: On iOS 8, I found the database I was looking for at a path like the following: `/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/155A6AAC-689C-49A4-93A5-F504E278D9B6/Documents/data.sqlite3`

Answer (score 0):

The Easiest way to do it by far is using iExplorer to download the file from your app. and then use [SQLite Professional read-only](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sqlite-professional-read-only/id635299994?mt=12) to read the file. 
Even thought it is not realtime but at least it is free. :-)

Comment: For remote debug purpose, I add a "send sqlite file by mail" in iOS App, so when client has some problems, they can send me the sqlite. However, I NEVER be able to open this sqlite from mail on MAC. I think it could be because of Sandbox protection. But is there any good way to open it?

Answer (score 0):

The Download Container method is the one I found to be the best. However, you have to be careful that some times, if you try to e-mail it or attach it from within the app then the file that is sent out would be empty.