# Editing sqllitedatabase over ssh on iPhone

Tags: iphone, sqlite, ssh

I have a jailbroken iPhone that allows ssh access. On the iphone is a sqllite database that I'd like to edit (add rows to tables and the like) (the overall goal is an assistive technology one - to make the app easier to use for people with disabilities)

Is it possible to programmatically edit (reasonable simply - a script would be fine) the database on the iphone over ssh, or would a better solution be to scp the database out, edit it programatically on local machine and then scp it back in?

(I've looked at [How do I access SQLite database instance on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159889/how-do-i-access-sqlite-db-instance-on-iphone?rq=1) but that appears to be for when you are building your own app - I'm just looking to edit a table over ssh...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to programmatically edit (reasonable simply - a script would be fine) the database on the iphone over ssh

Sure. Install the `SQLite 3.x` package from Cydia. Then you will have the `sqlite3` command line client with which you can edit those files.